# Creating a shopping cart page for multiple devices with Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shopping-cart, twitter-bootstrap-3

First off, thanks again for your help.

I like your response and it is what I was looking for up until the xs display. I'm trying to recreate somewhat the style of Amazon's shopping cart on smartphones.

I kept working at it and started with the mobile (xs) version and manage my way up but I still added a certain code twice. Didn't care much for that although I will hide all duplicate code from the widths in which I don't need it. I'm also going to remove it completely by using mobile detect from the corresponding device.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row show-grid">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs text-center">Subtotal (2 items): $636.80</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Proceed to Checkout</button></div>

            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-9">Items to buy now</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">Unit</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs">Qty</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">Total</div>

            <div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-xs"></div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/62x80/000/fff.png" alt="Item 1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6">Luxurious Leather Moto Jacket</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-sm-push-2 col-xs-3"><input type="number" value="2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-1 hidden-xs">$318.40</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">$638.40</div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 visible-xs">$318.40</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 visible-xs"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Update</button></div>

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-3 visible-xs"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-9"><ul><li>You save: $79.60 ( 20%)</li><li>In Stock</li><li>Eligible for FREE Super Saver Shipping</li></ul></div>

            <div class="col-xs-3 visible-xs"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 visible-sm col-xs-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Update</button></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Delete</button></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Save for Later</button></div>
            <!-- eof ITEM 1 -->

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 visible-xs"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-6 text-right">Subtotal: $318.40</div>

        </div>

        <div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-xs"></div>


        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 hidden-xs pull-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Checkout</button></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Continue Shopping</button></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to nest your columns and rows maybe: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Example: http://bootply.com/79747

**html**:

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
        <h1>shop</h1>

        <!-- nesting -->

        <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <!-- nesting -->
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">Heading</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">   
                <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">Article name</div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">Unit</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">Quality</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">Total</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">$122</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><select><option>10</option></select></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">$1220</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><button>delete</button></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><button>update</button></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
                subtotaal:
            </div>  
        </div>  
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
        <h3>Buttons</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-default col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">check out</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">shop more</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: I was actually trying to add my last change instead of editing and by doing so removing the original but didn't know if "Answer Your Question" was the appropriate way to go. Maybe it was.